# rufus scheduler not working

Tags: ruby, time, scheduler

I have a very simple script that I'm trying to run using Rufus:

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new  
start_time = Time.now   
data = [[0, 1, 15], [1, 2, 15]]

data.each do |datum|  
    scheduler.at start_time + datum[0] do   
       puts datum.inspect  
    end  
end
```

However, I"m finding that the script will simply terminate without executing. I've tried attaching a "scheduler.join" at the end of the do end block, and while this executes the script, it leaves the scheduler hanging. Is there a way to exit the process?

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple use case why use rufus-scheduler? Seems like sleep(datum[0]) is sufficient.